# Как разделить зависимости для SDK и мастер приложения?

Tags: android

Работаю над SDK. Есть необходимость чтобы SDK использовала material 1.6.1, а мастер приложение более старую версию. При подключении sdk к мастер приложению - происходит увеличение номера версии material для мастер приложения и начинаются проблемы.

Можно ли как то отделить зависимости sdk от зависимостей мастер приложения? Чтобы каждый модуль использовал свои зависимости.

Comment: Тогда приложение не будет компилироваться из-за дублирования классов.

Comment: Понял. Я избавился от material зависимости, но возникла проблема с bottom sheet. Он переехал из appCompat в material. Есть ли возможность достать его из appcompat? Если подключу support библиотеку наряду с appCompat - тоже будет конфликт?

Comment: Не советую - к своим багам добавите баги старых библиотек. Даже если соберётся и будет работать, то нет никакой гарантии, что не выстрелит в ногу нежданчиком. А в чём смысл извращений, интересно?

Comment: Есть конфликты с материал зависимостью sdk из мастер приложения

Comment: Подтягивайте приложение, невозможно собрать его так, что половина кода работает с одной версией приложения, а другая половина с другой.

Comment: Не, ну гипотетически можно форкнуть все зависимости, переименовать пакеты классов, исправить всё что из-за этого сломается и опубликовать. В библиотеке использовать эти модифицированные. Но куда проще будет исправить само приложение.